# Can i trace back in Netbeans debugger?

Tags: java, debugging, netbeans

I am currently developing a java application, I am trying to use the builtin debugger in Netbeans. I wanted to know how to trace back in the debugger.

Assuming I am executing the instructions line by line, if the program is currently executing 105th line of code and if i would want the program to go back and execute the 103rd line of code, how do i do it? Is this even possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read the below link. There is a concept of Pop Topmost Call which might help you.

http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqDebugBackup

Comment: Glad to help, anytime!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by setting a break point on 103 line. Then go the call trace and then on the call before to the current right click and do drop to frame. It will re execute that part. Then it will hit you break point on line 103.

I suggest you don't dot it multiple times in the same run. the state of the system becomes unstable for the run by doing this over and over again.